window cursor won't lock in games with ubuntu 24.04 (multi-screen setup)
I decided a few days ago to be an early adopter of 24.04 just to see how it goes and find some things to report in case i find some.
Well i did find something!
I have a 3 screen setup and would like to game on the middle one.
My issue is that the cursor won't stay in the game.
Already had this issue in the past so i know it can happen.
I had the issue with league of legends (before vanguard (RIP)) but i know it isn't a good example.
So let's talk about Dota 2 for now: it worked fine with 23.10 but the cursor started escaping as soon as i updated.
Got the same result with steam installed as flatpak and bare metal, as well as with gnome and kde with Wayland. Works fine with both X11 versions.
Must be due to some wayland upgrade but i am not knowledgeable enough in the area to know what. I didn't find find anything related in the changelog either.
I am taking any fix idea and hope we can find a solution (if it isn't already fixed) for the point release.
